# How to merge all sms came from a sender into one in a ListView, like in the default messaging app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a ListView showing all incoming sms. What I want to do is merge all sms by number, and just show the number of sms received by this sender, like in the main window of the default messaging app.

I use a list activity, which uses a cursor adapter to get all the messages like this :

```
public class MessageList extends ListActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        inboxcursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),new String [] {"person","address","body","date","_id","read", "status", "type", "reply_path_present", "subject","thread_id"} , null, null,"date DESC");
        smsadapter = new MessageListAdapter(this,inboxcursor);  
        getListView().setAdapter(smsadapter);
}

public class MessageListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        Context mcontext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MessageListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super(context, cursor, true);

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mcontext = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

             String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
             TextView numbertext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
             numbertext.setText(number);

             String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
             TextView messagetext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
             messagetext.setText(message);

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);

            return view;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you share your working code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, make an `ArrayList<String, int>` that will hold the data you want to display. String is the sms number of the sender, int is the count.
Then query for the incoming messages:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(<sms table, assuming all are incoming. if not, you need to filter it on your where clause>, new String[] {sender column name}, null, null, null};

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
  String sender = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnName(<sender column name>));
  // check if the sender string exists in your arraylist. if not, create a new entry and set count to 1. else, get the position of the existing number and increment count by one.
};
```

then feed this to a ListAdapter or ArrayAdapter. CursorAdapter won't cut it.

Comment: isn't there a way by implementing Filterable to my cursoradapter?

Comment: Filterable only filters the items in your adapter. It cannot transform your list in any way.

Comment: Oh ok.Before I using cursoradapter, I was using like you said an ArrayAdapter for incoming messages. The problem with ArrayAdapter and arraylist is that it is very slow to load,the ui thread waits (about 10 secs) before it gets everything and when I switch to asynctask, it is the same, the ui thread doesn't stop, the ui shows itself normaly and fast, but messages gets a lot of time to load like before about 10 secs. So nothing changes. My list to be more precise, contains a picture of the contact at the left, the contact name and number at the right, and under the name and number date and sms

Comment: so all this gets a lot of time when you have a lot of messages.

Comment: Can you be more precise please in your instructions, by giving me the exact code that I could type to get it all done. I can't get to manage if arraylist contains the number, and increment the count. A little more help would be very precious. How should my arrayadapter look? thanks for your help

Comment: @Samet could you give more insight to the code.I am posting one answer which is not giving apporopiate results ,what i wnat is to sum up the number of msgs from same sender in listview,so that there are no duplicate entries from same user.